# publishing content/task pane apps on Apache or any other webserver

Tags: office365, office-2013

I have a simple task pane app for MS Excel 2013 which I have tested by publishing on to a shared network drive. The network drive has only the Manifest xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>621f793f-18b4-4c46-993c-5776b36c9eb7</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.1</Version>
  <ProviderName>Microsoft IT</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Population 3" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Manages and interacts with settings that control the Population Visualization App in the Worksheet"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>http://mywebserver:8048</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="Workbook" />
  </Capabilities>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="http://mywebserver:8048/OA_HTML/WebAppCatalog/ExcelDataVisualizationWeb/App/PopulationVisualization/PopulationVisualizationTaskPane.html" />
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
</OfficeApp>
```

This works fine. I can find the app on the Shared Folder section of Apps for Office.

But I would like to deploy the app from a web server, preferably Apache. I understand that I can deploy this successfully from Sharepoint server. I do not find any documentation on MSDN about deploying from any other server other than Sharepoint.

Is deploying from servers like Apache not supported at all? Office just needs the manifest xml file. Is there any way to add the app manifest file using http url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, you cannot deploy manifest XML from an Apache server - the options for deploying an app for Office are:

1. To host the manifest in a shared file (as you are doing now)
2. Publish an app to an app catalog hosted in SharePoint
3. Submit/publish your app to the Office Store (if your app is allowed to be used publicly)

If you would like Microsoft to consider building this feature please feel free to submit it to the [Office/SP dev UserVoice](http://officespdev.uservoice.com/). This won't help you now, but at least the team *[disclaimer: of which I am a part of]* will be able to triage the request alongside the other stuff we're working on.